# Does this allocate new memory for the shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

If I have:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<M>> map;
.
.
.
.
while(something){
    std::shared_ptr<M> t = map[key];
    .
    .
}
```

Do I now have two `shared_ptr<M>`s- one still contained in the `unordered_map` and a copy of this, called `t`? Therefore I will also have two reference counting objects (one for `t` and one for `map[key]`) and two `M` memory allocations on the heap?

In other words all memory relating to `map[key]` has been **copied** for `t`?

Comment: You can't initialize a `shared_ptr` with the `int` expression `map[key]`.

Comment: `map[key]` is `int&`, not a `shared_ptr<M>`

Comment: `std::unordered_map` doesn't mean that you have to pass template argument in the other order than `std::map` ^_^.

Comment: Sorry got my wires crossed- have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you have

```
std::shared_ptr<M> t = foo();
std::shared_ptr<M> t2 = t;
assert(t.get() == t2.get()); // they point to the same data.
```

So you don't have another allocation for `M`. You have just increased the ref counting by one.

Answer (score 0):

The M object will NOT be copied but only the pointer of this object will be copied.
You have only one M object with the reference count '2'.
Don't worry about copying, the shared_ptr exists for this purpose. (*)